# Create a new column for data-table based on filtered value

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I want to filter a column and simultaneously create a new column for an existing [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) based on values of other columns on the earlier subset. Below is such an example -

```r
library(data.table)
X <- data.table(id = 1:5, L = letters[1:5])
X[id > 2, 'ss' := paste(id, L)]
X
   id L   ss
1:  1 a <NA>
2:  2 b <NA>
3:  3 c  3 c
4:  4 d  4 d
5:  5 e  5 e
```

However, as you see this is not returning the subset i.e. row number `3` through `5`, but the entire data table instead. Any pointer towards the correct and efficient approach will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you can apply them separately.

```
library(data.table)

Y <- X[id > 2][,ss := paste(id, L)]
Y
#   id L  ss
#1:  3 c 3 c
#2:  4 d 4 d
#3:  5 e 5 e
```

---

You can wrap `na.omit` to your attempt to remove `NA` values

```
na.omit(X[id > 2, 'ss' := paste(id, L)])
```

Or subset again

```
X[id > 2, 'ss' := paste(id, L)][id > 2]
```